# Resizing CATiledLayer's Using Scale Transforms vs. Bounds Manipulation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, calayer, catiledlayer

I've got my layer hosted workspace working so that using CATiledLayers for hundreds of images works nicely when the workspace is zoomed out substantially. All the images use lower resolution representations, and my application is much more responsive when panning and zooming large numbers of images.

However, within my application I also provide the user the ability to resize layers with a resize handle. Before I converted image layers to use CATiledLayers I was doing layer resizes by manipulating the bounds of the image layer according to the resize delta (mouse drag), and it worked well. But now with CATiledLayers in place, this is causing CATiledLayers to get confused when I mix resizing of layers through bounds manipulation and zooming/unzooming the workspace through scale transforms.

Specifically, if I resize a CATiledLayer to half the width/height size (1/4 the area), the image inside it will suddenly scale to a further 1/2 the resized frame leaving 3/4 of the frame empty. This seems to be exactly when the inner CATiledLayer logic gets invoked to provide a lower resolution image representation. It works fine if I don't touch the resize handler and just zoom/unzoom the workspace.

Is there a way to make zooming/resizing play nice together with CATiledLayers, or am I going to have to convert my layer resize logic to use scale transforms instead of bounds manipulations?

Comment: I ended up solving this by converting my layer resize logic to use scale transforms by overriding the setBounds: method for my custom image layer class to scale it's containing CATiledLayer, and repositioning accordingly. Also it is important to make sure the CATiledLayer's autoresizingMask is set to kCALayerNotSizable since we are handling resizes manually in setBounds:. Note: be sure to call the superclass's implementation of setBounds:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by converting my layer resize logic to use scale transforms by overriding the setBounds: method for my custom image layer class to scale it's containing CATiledLayer, and repositioning accordingly. Also it is important to make sure the CATiledLayer's autoresizingMask is set to kCALayerNotSizable since we are handling resizes manually in setBounds:.

Note: be sure to call the superclass's implementation of setBounds:.

Comment: Layers don't have autoresizing masks -- did you set the autoResizingMask on the layer's view to UIViewAutoresizingNone?

Comment: Layers do have autoresizing masks for Mac 10.5/6 desktop CALayers. For iOS, you are correct, they don't. However, I wasn't referring to iOS.